# How to test e2e google chrome extension with karma?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, integration-testing, karma-runner

I've found fantastic unit/e2e test tools [karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma).
And I wrote simple chrome extension with [angular](http://angularjs.org/). I want to write automated tests for it, but not only unit tests, end-to-end tests too.
I wrote something like this (will open my angular extension-options page):

```
 it('Go to options page', function() {
   browser().navigateTo('chrome-extension://aopgehikihpnclbfeohobanjecpiefho/html/application.html#/options');
 });
```

I removed '--user-data-dir' and '--disable-default-apps' for karma-chrome-launcher, (because I want that my extension stays in chrome during "karma tests")

but I've got next error message **"Sandbox Error: Application document not accessible."**:

```
    browser navigate to 'chrome-extension://aopgehikihpnclbfeohobanjecpiefho/html/application.html#/options'
    http://localhost:9876/base/tests/e2e/scenario.js?1372429335000:9:5: 

    Sandbox Error: Application document not accessible.

    Chrome 27.0 (Windows): Executed 2 of 2 (2 FAILED) (0.254 secs / 0.139 secs)
```

Chrome option **--no-sandbox** deprecated long time ago.

I'm sure I'm not wrong, the options page opens ok, but from chrome "omnibox".

```
chrome-extension://aopgehikihpnclbfeohobanjecpiefho/html/application.html#/options
```

Sandbox Error means **no way for end-to-end tests** for google chrome extensions via karma?
Can I set chrome to special "non-secure" mode just for tests?

Thanks,

Comment: https://github.com/salsita/chrome-angular-skeleton link to angular extension, it seems that no karma unit-tests and end-to-end tests for google chrome extension, so I have to write own unit test for it

Comment: Is application.html listed in the web-accessible-resources section of your extension's manifest?

Comment: yes I've got html/application.html in "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/*",
    "html/*",
    "css/*",
    "images/*"
  ],

Answer (score 2):

i don't think karma scenario runner is capable to do that. You can try [Protractor](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor), it uses WebDriver and karma scenario runner will be replaced with it.

Comment: I tried protractor and see that WebDriver opens extension option page OK (I observe it at the browser), but `Error: Angular could not be found on the page chrome-extension://ojkcpfmpkjjdmhmbgjdobncijnbgenbo/html/application.html#/options`. I'm noob with protractor and webdriver can I try to access to elements some different way ? I tried `ptor.findElement(protractor.By.bind('options_page'))`

Comment: i can't say much without seeing the code but are you bootstrap angular manually? also you may try other selectors to test like By.css.

Comment: Yes I [bootstrap angular manually](https://github.com/salsita/chrome-angular-skeleton/blob/develop/code/js/backgroundAngular.js#L29) due to require.js

Comment: Manual bootstrap is fine, but make sure you add ng-app on the root element, so that the angular scenario runner can find it...

Comment: i think i understand the problem. I send you a pull request (https://github.com/salsita/chrome-angular-skeleton/pull/1). You need to call angular.bootstrap after you added classes.Also i added a line to protractor, somehow window.name was not setting to DEFER_LABEL and bootstrap resume wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried setting a proxy? Like

```
proxies = {
    '/': 'chrome-extension://aopgehikihpnclbfeohobanjecpiefho/'
};
```

in your `karma-e2e.conf.js` file and then

```
browser().navigateTo('/html/application.html#/options');
```

in the test?

Comment: I've got: WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /html/application.html (Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT)
        browser navigate to '/html/application.html#/options'
        http://localhost:9876/base/tests/e2e/scenario.js?1374847487000:8:5: Sandbox Error: Application document not accessible.

Comment: Probably Karma proxies don't support chrome-extension. There might not be a solution until this is fixed. You could file an issue on Github.

Comment: I post my question to karma-runner group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/y-Lc29KyKIM

Comment: You might get a more authoritative answer (including future plans) if you post an issue on [Github](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues).